# Ultrium DT3 - Amber warning light and Red 3 on LED

Tags: dell-poweredge, lto-3, tapedrive, warning

Dell PowerEdge 2900 with IBM Ultrium DTO III installed.
Tape drive ejects and accepts tapes and backup software successfully writes to tape but I have a red 3 on the LED of the tape unit and a flashing amber light.  I have tried the online support at Dell and IBM but cannot find any article - even Google reveals nothing.  Any ideas on how to diagnose the issue - tape drive unit appears in in device manager although in other devices I do have an unknown - this could be something to do with it - or perhaps not?

Answer (score 1):

Placed LTO unit in maintenance mode (eject tape and press eject button 3 times in two seconds) and then took the LTO unit out of maintenance mode (with unit empty, press eject and hold for 3 seconds).

The display screen reset and the light became green once more.

Comment: See ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/systems/support/system_x_pdf/39m5625.pdf